# You roll 3 six-sided dice. What is the probability that the third is at least as high as the highest of the previous two?

Tags: probability, statistics

I know that the probability of the first two dice being different is $\frac56$, and the first/second being greater is $\frac56$, but am not sure how to calculate the prob of the 3rd being greatest.

(The answer key says $\frac{91}{216}$ or 42.13%)

Edit: Oops sorry I wrote the question wrong - it should be "at least as high as" the highest of the previous 2 instead of "higher than." Either way, thank you for the comprehensive responses! I think I got the answer now:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work according to the answer you were given, the problem should say "What is the probability that the third is higher than **or equal to** the highest of the previous two?" There are $6 * 6 * 6$ or $216$ possible throws. If you roll a $6$ with the third die, then you have to get $6-1$ with the other two, where there are $6 * 6$ or $36$ possibilities. Roll a $5$ and then you have to get $5-1$ with the other two which is $5 * 5$ or $25$. This same logic continues on and when you add all the possibilities you get $6^2+5^2+4^2+3^2+2^2+1^2=36+25+16+9+4+1$ which is $91$. Therefore, the probability is $91/216$.

However, if the problem is worded as you stated it, the answer is $55/216$ because the ranges the first and second dice can be will all be reduced by one so $5^2+4^2+3^2+2^2+1^2+0^2=25+16+9+4+1+0=55$

Answer (score 0):

One method: sum the following probabilities:

1. Third die=6, first two dice are each between 1 and 5
2. Third die=5, first two dice are each between 1 and 4
3. Third die=4, first two dice are each between 1 and 3
4. Third die=3, first two dice are each 1 or 2
5. Third die=2, first two dice are each 1

(I get 55/216, not 91/216)

Answer (score 0):

The total amount of possible throws with three dice is of course $6\cdot 6 \cdot 6 = 216$. If my third throw is a $6$, then I have $5\cdot5 = 25$ options with the other two dice such that the third throw is the higher than the other two.
In the same way, if the third is $5$, we have $4^2$ options, etc., etc.

This gives us $$5^2 + 4^2 + 3^2 + 2^2 + 1^1 = 55$$ possible options, instead of the $91$ the answer model gives, which difference is exactly $6^2$. We would include $6^2$ if the question had been that the third dice is the highest one, including equality. Is this the case?